# Export (or import) Exceptions list in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

In `Settings > Advanced > Privacy`, the following options are in use:

```
* Images > Do not show any images
* JavaScript > Do not allow any site to run JavaScript
```

Exceptions for sites are added as required. Managing the list in Chrome's interface is awkward. Every now and then you want to clean up old sites or temporarily add/remove a site.

Is there an easy way to export / import the lists? Alternatively, are the lists maintained in a file in human-readable form (and which could be manually edited)?

```
[Chrome > Settings > Images][1]
[Chrome > Settings > Images > Exceptions][2]
```